# Javascript: chaining two promises

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

Is it possible to chain promises while using the result of the previous called promise? I want to avoid writing spaghetti code like this.

```
getURL().then(function(a) {

    getURL().then(function(b) {
        var c = a + b;
    });
});
```

I'd much rather want something like this

```
var a = getURL();
a.then(function(b) {
    var c = a + b;
});
```

How do I run the getURL() twice and then have c calculated dependent on the result of promise 1 and promise 2.

Comment: Did you try this before posting?

Comment: Yes, that is possible, and probably the most common use case.   In your second example, b is the result whatever got resolved in a (in getURL).

Comment: just how do I get to run the getURL the second time and use the result of that? @matmo

Comment: [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), perhaps.

Comment: @Fullhdpixel I'm not sure what you're asking to be honest. Your original question is "`Is it possible to chain promises while using the result of the previous called promise"`? The answer is yes. You can chain as many promises as you want while passing previous results along. Your follow up question doesn't seem specific to promises, and its hard to suggest an approach without more context.

Answer (score 1):

Promise.all

```
Promise.all([Promise.resolve(1), Promise.resolve(2)]).then(([value1, value2]) => { 
  const c = value1 + value2; 
  .....
});
```